# How to create a final member variable in the constructor initialization list using named parameters in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, constants, initialization-list

I have this class that I want to initialize using named parameters, and using those parameters I create the `final` variable in the initialization list.
But whatever I try, it doesn't seem to work. I have it narrowed down to the following example:

```dart
class Test {
  const Test({
    Color color,
    BoxBorder border,
  }) : decoration = const BoxDecoration(color: const color, border: const border);

  final BoxDecoration decoration;
}
```

But when creating the `BoxDecoration` I'm getting the following error:
`The constructor returns type 'dynamic' that isn't of expected type 'Color'.`
The same error exists also for the border.
When I remove the `const` however, I get this:
`Invalid constant value.`

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think this is a valid use case and you should raise an issue on https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk

Comment: I've made an issue there, wondering now whether or not it is an actual bug. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: all the arguments of `const` constructor are `const` (constant at compile time) so by transitive property, iwe should be able to create a const object inside class using those arguments. (which is not allowed atm),

Answer (score 1):

I would have done it like below:

```
class Test {
   const Test({
    Color color,
    BoxBorder border,
  }): assert(color != null),
      assert(border != null),
      _color = color,
      _border = border;

  final Color _color;
  final BoxBorder _border;
  
  BoxDecoration get decoration  => BoxDecoration(color : _color, border: _border);
  
}
```

and then you can utilize it like this:

```
Container(decoration: Test(color: yourColor, border: yourBorder).decoration)
```

**Note that in your case _color and _border has been declered internally and are not accessible outside the Test class. The only accessible field is decoration.**

Comment: That works, however if you need to use the decoration often, this is a bit wasteful because you have to construct it each time, or is that negligible?